# Determine $k $.

Tags: number-theory, decimal-expansion

Let $a_n $ be the smallest number such that $n$ is the sum of the square of each digit of $a_n$. 
If $a_k =\overline {13d6}$ with $d $ being a digit, determine $k$.

example: $a_5=12$, $a_6=112$

What I thought:

-See that only $3\le d\le 6$ can works.

-Use the Lagrange's squares to conclude the $d $ that works exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_k=13d6$ means that 
$$k=1^2+3^2+d^2+6^2$$
and thus 
$$k=46+d^2$$

It is correct to awesome that $3\leq d \leq 6$ holds. 
If not, then a reordering of the number would be smaller, thus $a_k$ would not be smallest one.

Now, lets test these numbers:

$d=3 \Rightarrow k=55$

Here, with a naive approach of always using the highest possible number and putting it to the end of the number, we reach $a_{55}=1127$, lower than the number in question. Thus $d=3$ is not possible.

$d=4 \Rightarrow k=62$

Here,  $a_{62}=237$. Again lower than before.

$d=5 \Rightarrow k=71$

Here, we reach $a_{71} = 11128$, a possible candidate.

$d=6 \Rightarrow k=82$

Here, we reach $a_{82} = 19$, way lower.

So as all other candidates are way lower than $13d6$, $k=71$ holds!

Comment: I had a mistake right at the beginning, changed all results.

Comment: All number $N $ can be written like the sum of three squares if and only if $N\neq 4^k (8m+7) $, correct?

Comment: My intuition says that this is not true. Can you please elaborate why you think that? Maybe even ask a new question?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem

Comment: Ok! Never heard of that one. So what is your question if you have a wiki page? :D

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Yes you are right! I edited my answer